# howto cast a NSObject to my own class?

Tags: swift

Howto Cast a NSObject to a specific Class ?

```
var myclass1:MyClass1=MyClass1(NSObject);
```

Background :

I have a func which I can provide 2 different classes (MyClass1 & MyClass2) and in which I would like to cast the NSObject into one of these classes. Howto do that ?

```
func test(o1: NSObject){
     //var myclass1:MyClass1=MyClass1(NSObject); <- Problem
}
   class MyClass1: NSObject {
   }
   class MyClass2: NSObject {
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func test(o1: NSObject){

    if let myClass = o1 as? MyClass1{ //here you try to cast o1 to MyClass1
      // if cast is successful then we can access o1 properties
      myClass.someProperty = something
    }
}
```